# How to get images using Instagram API

Tags: php, instagram-api

How to get users images from [Instagram API](https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/)?

> access_token=4049241557.1677ed0.5324ad17d9314645b528ad112da8d56e

But no success, it's giving me only user info.
How can I get images using Instagram API?

Comment: check this link: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-the-instagram-api--cms-23608

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this API:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token={access-token}
```

This will get your photos,(but it looks like from the `access_token` you have posted, that user does not have any photos posted, so it will return empty array)

Use this to get other user's photo:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent?access_token={access-token}
```

you should have authenticated with `public_content` scope and if you are in sandbox mode, only sandbox users can be accessed until your app is reviewed and live

Comment: Hi @krisrak how to approve public_content and relationship permission. I submitted my app but they declined both permission.

Comment: what does your app do?

Comment: Publishers create a gate and add track to download for other users, he also add a instagram username to follow.
If a user wants to download that track then he must follow that instagram user.
I'm using PHP api for it.

Comment: i dont think it is a valid usecase and does not comply with the API policy: `A.18. Don't participate in any "like", "share", "comment" or "follower" exchange programs.` https://www.instagram.com/about/legal/terms/api/

Comment: Okay
They provide an api to follow users if its not legal then whats the use of that api.
I tested in sandbox its working for sandbox users.

Comment: u can like for a business use case, not for `exchange program`

Comment: yes its a business, we wants to promote our business using this api

Comment: The remaining Instagram Legacy API permission ("Basic Permission") was disabled on June 29, 2020. As of June 29, third-party apps no longer have access to the Legacy API. To avoid disruption of service to your app and business, developers previously using the Legacy API should instead rely on Instagram Basic Display API and Instagram Graph API. Please request approval for required permissions through the App Review process. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api

Answer (score 0):

You could use this library [Cosenary](https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API).

```
use MetzWeb\Instagram\Instagram;

$instagram = new Instagram(array(
    'apiKey'      => 'YOUR_APP_KEY',
    'apiSecret'   => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
    'apiCallback' => 'YOUR_APP_CALLBACK'
));

// grab OAuth callback code
$code = $_GET['code']; 
// or maybe $code = $request->code; // if you are using Laravel
$data = $instagram->getOAuthToken($code);

// set user access token
$instagram->setAccessToken($data);

// and
$pictures = $instagram->getUserMedia();
```

Read the documentation for more information.

Hope this helps.