# Unable to get images from Instagram by using the provided PHP API

Tags: php, curl, instagram-api

I am trying to the Instagram PHP API to get friends photos. I registered as a sandbox user as well as a dummy user with few random images posted.Then, I invited the dummy user to grant the app in sandbox to connect his account.

To get access token I send a request to get code and then get access token with scope:

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=SECRET_STRING&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http://localhost/&code=CODE&scope=basic+public_content+comments+likes`
```

PHP code:

```
$url = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token';
    $payload = [
            $GLOBALS['KEY_CID'] => $GLOBALS['VAL_CID'],
            $GLOBALS['KEY_CECRET'] => $GLOBALS['VAL_CECRET'],
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost/',
            'code' => $param_code,
            'scope' => 'basic+public_content+comments+likes'];

$ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // url
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); // POST
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload); // POST DATA
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // RETURN RESULT true
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // RETURN HEADER false
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0); // NO RETURN BODY false / we need the body to return
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); // VERIFY SSL HOST false
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // VERIFY SSL PEER false
$response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
curl_close($ch);
```

After I got access token successfully.

I try to get images from a sandbox user which is a dummy account I created for testing:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/fane.leee/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

PHP code for retrieving image:

```
$url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/fane.leee/media/recent?access_token='.$ACCESS_TOKEN;
    $ch = curl_init(); // initializing
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url ); // API URL to connect
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 ); // return the result, do not print
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30 );
    $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true); // connect and get json data
    curl_close($ch);
```

**The problem**
The $response of the get image request is `NULL` without error message. Anyone got any ideas about the problem?

Thanks.

---

Reference

1. Instagram development doc [authentication](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/) and [authorization](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/).
2. Instagram development doc about [user endpoints](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/)
3. Another [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40105795/how-to-get-images-using-instagram-api) about Instagram web API

---

Development environment:
Ubuntu 16.04
Apache2
PHP 7.0.8
MySQL 14.14

---

Edit 1: Add the PHP code calling cUrl functions.
Edit 2: If I replace the user id 'fane.leee' by using 'self', I am able to retrieve the images I posted. I also followed the user 'fane.leee'. Any else I should do to retrieve the friends' media?

Comment: Post some code please.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, code added :)

Comment: Have you added any sandbox users?

Comment: Yes, as I described in the first paragraph, I created a dummy account, post few images and add the dummy account as a sandbox user. As the result, the dummy use's user id is listed in the `sandbox users` list. So there are two users in the `sandbox users` list under the admin name, one is the `admin` the other is the dummy user who is accepted the invitation. Cheers :)

Comment: From the documentation you posted, it looks like:

    `$GLOBALS['KEY_CID'] => $GLOBALS['VAL_CID'],
    $GLOBALS['KEY_CECRET'] => $GLOBALS['VAL_CECRET'],`

should be:

   `  'client_id' => $GLOBALS['VAL_CID'],  'client_secret' => $GLOBALS['VAL_CECRET'], `

Comment: I defined some global variables somewhere else. (also realize those are kind of pointless later) The value of those variable are 'client_id' and 'client_secret'. I was copy and paste the code and forgot to replace variables by their values. Since I could use the token to get media from the user 'self'. I thought the token query should be good. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `fane.leee` is a username. Instagram requires a user id in the API caller.

To get a user id by calling a instagram API function, we could use
`https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1`

Another way to get the user id is to use a 3rd party website. It is able to retrieve an Instagram user id from a username. It is [here](https://smashballoon.com/instagram-feed/find-instagram-user-id/)

---

Reference:
An answer from Thinh Vu in [this thread - Not the accepted answer, but the answer underneath. P.S the accepted answer is not working anymore.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796349/instagram-how-to-get-my-user-id-from-username)